# Sqlite data reader for Windows phone 8.1

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8.1

Currently SQLite for windows phone 8.1 doesn't come with SQLite Data reader, But I need to read  data from SQLite DB without knowing the Type in advance , this is because the Table data and schema can change externally (Outside of my application).

So is there any way to read the SQLite table data as below

```
var connection = new SQLiteConnection(dbName);
connection.Query<T>("Select * from Table")
```

where T is unknown?

Alternatively , is it possible to create T dynamically from the Column list obtained from the connection.GetTableInfo("Table name")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Andy Wigley's SQLiteWinRT wrapper which supports plain non-typed SQL (https://sqlwinrt.codeplex.com/).

You can either use plain old statements:

```
// Get the file from the install location  
var file = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("cities.db");  

// Create a new SQLite instance for the file 
var db = new Database(file);  

// Open the database asynchronously
await db.OpenAsync(SqliteOpenMode.OpenRead);

// Prepare a SQL statement to be executed
var statement = awaitdb.PrepareStatementAsync(
  "SELECT rowid, CityName FROM Cities;"); 

// Loop through all the results and add to the collection
while (awaitstatement.StepAsync())
   items.Add(statement.GetIntAt(0) + ": "+ statement.GetTextAt(1));
```

Or you can use prepared statements (which is certainly better as it provides more modularity):

```
// Prepare a SQL statement to be executed with a parameter
var statement = await db.PrepareStatementAsync(
  “SELECT rowid, CityName FROM Cities WHERE CityName LIKE ?;”);

// Bind the parameter value to the statement
statement.BindTextParameterAt(1, “c%”);

// Loop through all the results and add to the collection
// Same as above
```

As you can see the queries return simple strings which you can use to construct your objects. Or you can work directly with those (you mentioned that you don't necessarily know about the underlying objects).

Here is another tutorial that should get you started: http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/05/30/sqlite-winrt-wrapper-for-windows-phone/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I am not sure if this library also works fine for Win phone 8.1 application, I will give it a try and get back to you. Thanks again. The site does inform " The latest update of the library supports Windows Phone 8 development in addition to Windows 8 development." So hopefully this will work for us, I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: Since Andy showed an example in a WP 8.1 jumpstart talk I'm quite positive that it'll work ;)

Comment: Yes..It worked for us, I am bit worried about the licensing and support for this library, but it does what I wanted to do so thanks and I accepted this as the answer.